# functions on Riemann sphere

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $C$ a complex riemann surface (compact). Take $f$ a meromorphic funtion on $C$. This function defines a function $\pi:C \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^1_{\mathbb{C}}$. 
How can i define a function $f^{'} : \mathbb{P}^1_{\mathbb{C}}  \rightarrow  \mathbb{P}^1_{\mathbb{C}} $ such that $f=\pi^{*} f^{'}$. (the * is the pull-bACK)

Comment: i think you know what is $\pi$. Here i write a short definition. In this way we are sure that we are talking about the same things. Simply $\pi$, for a point $p \in C$ takes the value $f(p)$ if $p$ is not a pole. Viceversa $f(p)=\infty$. I've found the assertion that it is possible to write $f$ as the pull-back as in the question. Iìve thought at a rational function on $\mathbb{P}^1$ since the fields of the meromorphic funtions on the riemann sphere is equal to the set of all rational functios respect to the variable $z$

Comment: i think that is not the right answer because if you take $f^{'}=id$ you should have $f=f^{'} \circ \pi=\pi$ But $f$ is meromorphic and $\pi$ is holomorphic

Comment: i think that $f^{'}$ must be a meromorphic function on tha riemann sphere. The identity is not.

Comment: ok. Now i clear my confusion. The identity works. Thanks